# Function object __proto__ and prototype property

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to figure out the prototype chain of a function that I wrote

```
function Animal(voice)
 {
  this.voice = voice|| 'meaw'
  }

  Animal.prototype.speak =function() {
  console.log(this.voice);
  }
```

I know that the Animal function has a prototype property which point to it's prototype object. It's prototype object has constructor which points back and **__proto__** property which points to Object object prototype

I am aware that every function object inherits from **Function**'s object **prototype** and which inherit from Object's object **prototype** including **__proto__** property. Now when I further investigated it, I found out that **Function's** object **prototype** and **__proto__** property links to the same prototype object.

```
console.log(Animal.__proto__.constructor.__proto__  == Animal.__proto__.constructor.prototype ); //true
console.log(Animal.__proto__.constructor.__proto__ == Animal.__proto__); //true
```

Then I did some further test to prove it

```
Animal.__proto__.constructor.__proto__.test = 28;

console.log(Animal.__proto__.constructor.__proto__.test); // prints 28
console.log(Animal.__proto__.test);  //prints 28
```

That means it's prototype and the prototype from it is inheriting are same. Any reason why it is set like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already know that `Object.getPrototypeOf(Animal)` (or `Animal.__proto__`) is the [`Function.prototype` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype). So let's drop that `Animal` thing and just repeat your equations with `Function.prototype`:

```
Function.prototype.constructor.__proto__ == Function.prototype.constructor.prototype // true
Function.prototype.constructor.__proto__ == Function.prototype // true
```

Now, the `.constructor` property of `Function.prototype` (like for all well-defined prototype objects) points to its respective constructor, the [`Function` constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function). So we've got

```
Function.__proto__ == Function.prototype // true
Function.__proto__ == Function.prototype // true
```

Now, given that `Function` is a function, it only makes sense that it inherits from `Function.prototype` like all other functions do.

This is what your testing confirms, as you basically did

```
Function.__proto__.test = 28;

Function.__proto__.test // 28
Function.prototype.test // 28
```

And yes, `Function.test` and `Animal.test` would yield `28` as well now.

Comment: Alright it make sense. But don't you think it should be true for Object too since it is also an object but Object.prototype == Object.__proto__ is false

Comment: The `Object` constructor, while also being `instanceof Object`, is foremost a function and `Object.prototypeOf(Object) == Function.prototype`. `Function` is the only builtin object whose internal *[[prototype]]* (inheritance link) points to the same object as its `.prototype` property.

Answer (score 1):

This is how Javascript lookup chain works.

First note that

```
Animal.__proto__ === Function.prototype \\true
Animal.__proto__.constructor === Function \\true
```

Because for any function `A`,

```
A.prototype.constructor === A
```

---

Then the question becomes, what is the `__proto__` property of `Function`? It is `Function.prototype`.

```
Function.__proto__ === Function.prototype \\true
```

This is somehow weird because these two properties are not usually the same.

Usually, when `a = new A();`

```
a.__proto__ === A.prototype \\true
```

An instance's `__proto__` property equals its constructor's `prototype`;
But consider that every function is the instance of `Function` and `Function` itself is a function too. `Function` is the constructor of itself!

```
Function.constructor === Function //true
```

It makes more sense now.

---

Now we look back at the question.

```
Animal.__proto__.constructor.__proto__.test = 28;
```

is equvalent to:

```
Function.__proto__.test = 28;
```

is equvalent to:

```
Function.prototype.test = 28;
```

So it is now clear that the two `console.log` print out the same because:

```
Animal.__proto__ === Function.prototype \\ture
```

As we said at the very beginning.

Comment: Thank you Quarter2Twelve. You also explained it well!

Answer (score 1):

`Animal` is a function and like all functions (unless you modify it), it links back to the `Function.prototype` object. So:

```
Animal.__proto__ === Function.prototype //true
```

Now if we replace `Animal.__proto__` with `Function.prototype`, we get:

```
Function.prototype.constructor.__proto__ === Function.prototype
```

Why is that? `Function.prototype.constructor` links back to its constructor, which is the `Function` constructor. So this actually means:

```
Function.__proto__ === Function.prototype
```

If you're wondering why both `Function.__proto__` and `Function.prototype` share the same value, have a look at the specification.

[The `Function` constructor `[[Prototype]]` (a.k.a `Function.__proto__`) is defined as follows in the specification:](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-function-constructor:)

> The Function constructor is itself a built-in function object. The
>   value of the [[Prototype]] internal slot of the Function constructor
>   is **%FunctionPrototype%**, the intrinsic Function prototype object
>   (19.2.3).

[The `Function.prototype` property shares the same value:](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function.prototype)

> The value of Function.prototype is **%FunctionPrototype%**, the intrinsic
>   Function prototype object (19.2.3).

So, since both `Function` and the result of `new Function()` are functions, they share the same `[[Prototype]]`:

```
var func = new Function()
Function.__proto__ === func.__proto__
```

Comment: Thank you nils for the specification's reference!

Answer (score 0):

> I found out that Function's object prototype and **proto** property links to the same prototype object.

You are mixing "prototype property" and "prototype object".

`.prototype` is a property on constructor function. Whenever constructor is called, it creates object with *prototype object* set to `Constructor.prototype`.

```
function Animal(){}
let animal = new Animal();
animal.__proto__ = Animal.prototype;
```

In fact, `__proto__` property is just getter defined on `Object.prototype` that calls `Object.getPrototypeOf`.

Your confusion is caused by fact that `Object.getPrototypeOf(Animal) === Function.prototype` (all functions are instances of `Function`) and Function constructor/prototype is twisted.

```
Function.prototype === Function.__proto__; // true
typeof Function.prototype; // "function"
```